# jqGrid weird exception upon calling databind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have been using the latest MVC dll from [Trirand](http://trirand.net/download.aspx) and I am using the JqGrid.Databind() function to get data from the controller. Here is the code that I have written:

```
var listToBind = gridDataTable.Cast<IDictionary>().ToDataSource();
gridModel.ResourcePlanningGrid.DataSource = null;

JsonResult returnObject;
try
{
    returnObject = gridModel.ResourcePlanningGrid.DataBind(listToBind.AsQueryable());
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Unknown Exception: delete the current session that holds the grid and 
    //restart the whole page 
    this.Session["ResourcePlanningGrid"] = null;
    return FilterData();
}
```

Intermittently it throws an exception on the .DataBind() call that says that it parses a string that is not a valid Boolean. Has anyone encountered this before? Is there an existing fix for this? or should I find another way to pass values from a list to bind?

Here is the the exception stack trace.

```
   at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)
   at System.Convert.ToBoolean(String value)
   at Trirand.Web.Mvc.JQGrid.get_AjaxCallBackMode()
   at Trirand.Web.Mvc.JQGrid.DataBind()
   at Trirand.Web.Mvc.JQGrid.DataBind(Object dataSource)
   at Cormant.OrangeReports.Web.Controllers.ResourcePlanningController.FilterData(Nullable`1 customerID, Nullable`1 projectID, Nullable`1 startDate, Nullable`1 endDate, String employeeID) in e:\Projects\OrangeReports\Cormant.OrangeReports.Web\Controllers\ResourcePlanningController.cs:line 175
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: well are you trying to parse a string into a boolean that is not "true" or "false"?   I'll bet after digging in code you are somewhere

Comment: Actually no, I'm just using a built in function. Passing a datasource object. Let me add more detail to the question.